# How to create the same structure of tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset from pandas

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

`tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` creates a TF Dataset ready for Kears supervised training.

```
titanic_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file("titanic_train.csv", "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv")
titanic = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    titanic_file,
    label_name="survived",
    batch_size=1,   # To compre with the head of CSV
    shuffle=False,  # To compre with the head of CSV
    header=True,
)
for row in titanic.take(1):  # Take the first batch 
    features = row[0]        # Diectionary
    label = row[1]
    
    for feature, value in features.items():
        print(f"{feature:20s}: {value}")
    
    print(f"label/survived      : {label}")    
-----
sex                 : [b'male']
age                 : [22.]
n_siblings_spouses  : [1]
parch               : [0]
fare                : [7.25]
class               : [b'Third']
deck                : [b'unknown']
embark_town         : [b'Southampton']
alone               : [b'n']
label/survived      : [0]
```

How to create the same from Pandas? Tried below but the label is dictionary instead of int32.

```
df = pd.read_csv(titanic_file)
titanic_from_pandas = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'survived']),
    dict(df.loc[:, ['survived']])
))
for row in titanic_from_pandas.batch(1).take(1):  # Take the first batch 
    features = row[0]        # Diectionary
    label = row[1]
    
    for feature, value in features.items():
        print(f"{feature:20s}: {value}")
    
    print(f"label/survived      : {label}")    
---
sex                 : [b'male']
age                 : [22.]
n_siblings_spouses  : [1]
parch               : [0]
fare                : [7.25]
class               : [b'Third']
deck                : [b'unknown']
embark_town         : [b'Southampton']
alone               : [b'n']
label/survived      : {'survived': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0])>}  <-----
```

By the way, the data structure ready for Keras supervised training is (features, labels) but which document defines it?

Comment: Just take `df['survived']`. You clearly pass dict to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`, so you get dict, I don't get where the problem is :P

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit defines what should be passed to `.fit()`

Answer (score 0):

As @Proko suggested.

```
titanic_from_pandas = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(df.loc[:, df.columns != 'survived']),
    df.loc[:, 'survived']
))
for row in titanic_from_pandas.batch(1).take(1):  # Take the first batch 
    features = row[0]        # Diectionary
    label = row[1]
    
    for feature, value in features.items():
        print(f"{feature:20s}: {value}")
    
    print(f"label/survived      : {label}")    
---
sex                 : [b'male']
age                 : [22.]
n_siblings_spouses  : [1]
parch               : [0]
fare                : [7.25]
class               : [b'Third']
deck                : [b'unknown']
embark_town         : [b'Southampton']
alone               : [b'n']
label/survived      : [0]
```